# How do I fix this issue? Issue is written as comment in code

Tags: java

```
// This is java code 
//  it is saying comparable is a raw type, references to generic type comparable 
  <T> should be parameterized. I have never recieved this error before so I    
   don't know how to resolve the issue.  



package edu.swosu.wordcraft.timers;


    /** The base (and abstract) class for timer events */
    public abstract class Event implements Comparable {
protected long time;
 protected long delay;

/** Constructs new timer.  
 * This determines current system time and adds the appropriate 
       time based on the delay parameter. 
 * 
 * Note that this does not automatically add itself to the timer thread
 * 
 * @param delay     Delay for the timed event (in milliseconds) 
 */
public Event(long delay) {
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() + delay;
    this.delay = delay;
}

/** Implements Comparable interface - compares value of time parameter 
 * 
 */
public int compareTo(Object otherEvent) {
    if(!(otherEvent instanceof Event)) {
        //this really shouldn't happen
        throw new ClassCastException("Invalid Onject during Even compare");
    }

    long otherTime = ((Event)otherEvent).getTime(); 

    if (this.time > otherTime) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        if (this.time < otherTime) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public long getTime() {
    return time;
}

/** method to be called when timer fires
 *  
 */

public abstract void execute();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it informs you, that you have to provide the class to which the class implementing `Comparable` could been compared with. In your case, if you want to compare `Event` with `Event`, you could simply write

```
implements Comparable<Event>
```

Comment: Sorry, not intended :-)

Comment: If I make this change though the line. public int compareTo(Object otherEvent) will then have errors.